# Is there a way to get a BeautifulSoup web page description without ellipses?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Using bs4, I found a way to get the title and description of a web page, but the description is cut into pieces with ellipses, like this `"Everything you need to know about how-to adopt a cat, bringing your new cat... Browse cat breeds and learn about the many cats available for adoption on..."`

Here is my code:

```
def get_data(search):
    headers = {"user-agent" : get_headers()} # get_headers is just the value of a file with viewing headers
    response = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", params={"q" : search}, headers = headers)
    
    results = page_info(response.content)
    return results

def page_info(page):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
    names = soup.find_all("h3", class_ = "LC20lb DKV0Md")
    links = soup.find_all("cite", class_ = "iUh30 Zu0yb qLRx3b tjvcx")
    desc = soup.find_all("div", class_ = "VwiC3b yXK7lf MUxGbd yDYNvb lyLwlc")
    parsed_data = [{"title":title.text, "link":link.text.replace(" › ","/"), "desc":desc.text} for title, link, desc in zip(names, links, desc)]
    return parsed_data
```

Is there a way to go get the description without `...` in the middle? Thanks
EDIT: to be more clear, I meant getting the full description, or at least more full than the one provided.

Answer (score 0):

you can split that string and then make a new string out of  it

```
disc = "Everything you need to know about how-to adopt a cat, bringing your new cat... Browse cat breeds and learn about the many cats available for adoption on..."

#this splits the description by '...' and returns array
splited = disc.split('...')

#now join the elements in array and make another string out of it
final = ''.join(splited)
# you can change this line to final = ' '.join(splited) and add space between those splited strings
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove (or replace) any part of a string with `String.replace()`

example:

```
original_str = "abc ... 123... abc"
corrected_str = original_str.replace('...', '')
print(original_str)
print(corrected_str)
```

output:

```
abc ... 123... abc
abc  123 abc
```

Comment: Yes, but then the string wouldn't make sense with two sentences combined at random places like "bringing your new cat Browse cat breeds and learn".

Comment: The question was not about making a sentence make sense, it was about removing ellipses from a string. I'm not questioning OP's logic, I'm simply helping them with their issue. If you wish, you could instead of replacing ellipses with an empty string, replace them with a period. i.e `original_str.replace('...', '.')`. That wouldn't necessarily make more sense than an empty string for every case. but it's possible